# ASP NET MVC 6 - How to get Product count for each enum value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I have developed a Site using asp net mvc 6, I have used `enom` as categories, now I need to get product count under each `enom` value,

Here is my enum look like,

```
namespace ecom.Data
{
    public enum BookCategory
    {
        Action,
        Comedy,
        Drama,
        Others
    }
}
```

What I want is get products count under this enoms,

[See here, Front view without product count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5dRr.png)

This is my Controller Looks like,

```
using ecom.Data.Services;

namespace ecom.Controllers;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    
    private readonly IBooksService _service;
    
    public async Task <IActionResult> BookView(string slug)
    {
        
        var data = await _service.GetBookBySlugAsync(slug);

        if(data == null) return View("NotFound");
        return View("BookView", data);
    }
```

This is model which i use as product model,

```
namespace ecom.Models
{
    public class Book:IEntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
        //enom
        public BookCategory BookCategory { get; set; }
        //Relationships
        public List<Writter_Book> Writter_Books { get; set; }
        //Publisher
        public int PublisherId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
        public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My cshtml view right now,

```
@foreach (var cat in Html.GetEnumSelectList<BookCategory>())
{
    <li><a href="#">@cat.Text <span>()</span></a></li>
}
```

I want to get product count to above inside foreach's span tag,
Anyone can help me with that??

Comment: You'll need to do something like group by the enum and then take the counts of the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `Count` to achieve your goal.

Something like

```
myBooksDataSource
    .GroupBy(book => book.BookCategory)
    .Select(group => new { Category = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });
```

Which will output a collection of (BookCategory, Count).

```
{ BookCategory.Action, 20 }
{ BookCategory.Comedy, 204 }
```

You can create a class to hold that data if you need to pass it around.

```
public class BookCategoryCountData
{
    public BookCategory Category { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and select using that object.

```
public IEnumerable<BookCategoryCountData> GetBookCountByCategory()
{             
     return _context.Books
         .GroupBy(book => book.BookCategory)                 
         .Select(group => new BookCategoryCountData() { 
             Category = group.Key, 
             Count = group.Count() 
         });
 }
```

Comment: I added below code to BookServices but i can't return value from the service it giving an error when i try to return,
`public Task<Book> GetBookCount()
        {
            var result = _context.Books
                .GroupBy(book => book.BookCategory)
                .Select(group => new { Category = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });
            
            
            return result;
        }`
Error:
`
(local variable) IQueryable<'a> result
Types:

   

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: ecom.Data.BookCategory Category, int Count>>

Comment: Your return type is Task<Book>, but this query returns that anonymous { BookCategory, Int32 } type.

Comment: yes im using async, I tried call it without Task as well, also it won't work same error, Can you explain from where I can call it, if I can't use service

Comment: You can use Task if you want, you just need to adjust the return type.  I updated my answer to include a concrete type.  The issue was the type you tried returning, `Book`, but this data is not that type.  I removed `Task<T>` wrapper to show the return type more easily.

Comment: Is there any way to add **enum value** to `Class BookCategoryCountData` along with category and count, cause without enum value I can't add anchor link to redirect categories

I tried to call enum directly from view also but it won't give value 
`BookCategory enumData = (BookCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(BookCategory), string);`

Comment: The value is the actual underlying type, which in your case is likely Int32.  To get the Name from the enum value, you can use `Enum.GetName(typeof(BookCategory), category)` or you can get it in that database call using `group.Key.ToString()`

Comment: It worked that way  like u earlier mentioned, `(int)thisItm.Category` Enum problem solved. Asp Net debugging kind of hard view of my point